# Perl regular expression syntax for multiple alternative strings

Tags: perl, syntax

```
use File::Find;
find(sub { -f && /\.tmp$/ && unlink }, '.')
```

A Perl script for deleting *.tmp files. My problem is in getting it to search for multiple extensions, such as *.tmp OR *.tmp2. I've tried a handful of variations such as

```
find (sub { -f && /\.tmp$,.tmp2$/ && unlink }, '.')
```

but I can't seem to solve what I'm sure is a simple syntax problem.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really specific to `File::Find`. You're just using ordinary regular expression matching, so you need a regexp that matches multiple extensions, e.g.

```
/\.tmp2?$/
```

The `?` means that the expression before it (the `2` in this case) is optional. In the more general case, you could write:

```
/\.(ext1|ext2|ext3)$/
```

to match 3 different extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions (here: `/\.tmp$/` or `/\.tmp$,.tmp2$/`) are a language of themselves – read the [Perl Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for an introduction. To specify alternative patterns, we don't use the comma (it has no special meaning in Perl regexes) but the pipe: `|`

```
/\.tmp$|\.tmp2$/
```

which means “either the literal string `.tmp` at the end of string or the literal string `.tmp2` at the end of string”. We could simplify this as

```
/[.]tmp[2]?$/
```

which means “the literal string `.tmp`, optionally followed by a `2`, at the end of the string”.

Answer (score 0):

You could try usign a regular expression. In this example I added `\d*` to match optional digits after the `tmp` string.

As a one-liner:

```
perl -MFile::Find -e 'find(sub { -f && m/\.tmp\d*$/ && unlink }, q|.|)'
```